# How do you add a ":hover" effect on Elm without using signals?

Tags: css, functional-programming, elm

I want to add a `:hover` style to an element using Elm's HTML library. I could do it using Signals and Sets to keep track of selected nodes, but that would bloat my code with unecessary state for something trivial. I could do it by adding an external stylesheet, but I still didn't figure how to do it using elm-reactor.

So, how can I add a `:hover` style to an element using Elm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the 'identicalsnowflake/elm-dynamic-style' library might help:

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/identicalsnowflake/elm-dynamic-style/1.1.0

```
div (hover [("color","blue","lightblue")]) [text "so cool!"]
```

Comment: That still doesn't answer how I load a sheet, but solves the problem perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome :)   I'm not sure how to add css stylesheets in the elm-reactor I'm afraid.  I think the Elm community is steadily growing - it seems to be a very promising option for web UIs and games.

Comment: There is a open [issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-reactor/issues/138) for this one. But again there is work around [here](http://boonofcode.svbtle.com/)